# Normalization; how to judiciously determine if a field is dependent on a prime attribute for its existence?

Tags: database, database-design, dependencies, normalization, database-normalization

Mainly concerning partial dependencies (2nd Normal Form)

Say, you're designing a database for a train service, and would like to keep track of its data in relation to its scheduled and actual departure and arrival times. Now, given that the scheduled departure time is part of the composite key for a particular table, consider the following:

Would you say that even for the scheduled arrival time attribute, is that attribute actually dependent on the scheduled departure time for its existence? Arguably, given that there was substantial research and work gone into determining the travel duration between two train stations, and thus, one could determine a very close approximate for the arrival time, given its scheduled departure time (the key/prime attribute), does that mean the scheduled arrival time is dependent on the scheduled departure time?

Similarly, for the actual departure and arrival times, would you say either of these two attributes depends on the scheduled departure time? How can you be judicious about this as a database designer?

Comment: You cannot know what a table's keys are without first knowing its functional dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Functional Dependency A->B simply means that for any given value of A there is exactly one possible value for B.

In practice a database designer is usually interested in FDs which represent business rules that the user/customer expects or needs to be enforced. The reason for enforcing those rules is to help ensure an accurate and usable representation of data.

I have little knowledge of rail timetables except from the point of view of a passenger. I see examples in timetables where different trains following identical routes and stops do in fact take different times to reach a destination. I expect that's because at peak periods extra time needs to be allowed due to congenstion for example. So I would guess that depature time does *not* by itself determine arrival time. Unless you actually intend to enforce the departure->arrival dependency there is no need to consider it as part of normalization. If in doubt then as database designer you ought to be able to ask a subject-matter expert or business sponsor to determine whether that FD might be important in the database.

Suppose a train timetable is represented as a relation that looks like this:

```
Timetable {service, origin, destination, departure, arrival}
```

In this design, departure time alone wouldn't determine arrival time because trains at different stations could start at the same time and make different journeys with very different arrival times. Even for a given origin station and a given departure time there might be different services with different arrival times (the Sunday 0830 service might arrive at a different time to the Monday 0830 service on the same route).

Let's assume a candidate key of {service, origin, destination, departure}, in which case the obvious key depdendency for arrival would be enforced: {service, origin, destination, departure}->{arrival}. Departure would therefore be a prime attribute but would not by itself be a determinant of arrival. Perhaps an interesting question is whether {service, origin, destination, arrival} is also a candidate key. I suspect that might be an unreasonable restriction for some busy rail networks. Even my assumption of the {service, origin, destination, departure} candidate key might be unrealistic for some senarios I suppose - but this is just my hypothetical example. The only way to answer these questions properly is to do the analysis in the actual business domain and talk to the domain experts.